# Searching text knowing <i tag class

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to get div text with class _50x4 using 5pxsel:

```
 <div...>
       <i class="5pxsel">
     <div>
       <div>
         <div class="_50x4">
             Work in 
             <a>London</a>
         <div class="_50x4">
             Work in 
             <a> Germany </a>
```

I need to get text  using  class 5pxsel, not _50x4, and get only first result -  'Work in London'.

Comment: I have my attempts of doing this, but I didn't post it, coz they are useless.

Comment: it doesn't matter, this is very basic xpath/css identifier, just spending 5 minutes on google will give you answer.

Answer (score 0):

trt with following x-path

```
//*[@class="5pxsel"]/following-sibling::div/div/div[@class='_50x4']
```